# Filtering arrays in hive

Tags: hive, hql

I have a hive table in that I am having a column called `paid_value` in an array format for each record.

Now I want to filter the array such that the value must be between 1000 and 10000 for each record.

I don't know how to do it.

I know `array_contains(Array<T>, value)` function but this doesn't solve my problem since it accepts only one value as a checking criteria but I want like 'between 1000 and 10000'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE` to explode the array and then do the filter subsequently. But if your array size is huge, your process will be slow.

Other option definitely needs a UDF to do the filter.
The other workaround I can think of is doing with a brickhouse UDF is:

-- this will give you an array of numbers between start(st) and end(ed)

```
select collect_set(pe.i+1) as range_array
from
(SELECT 1000 as st, 1100 as ed) t
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(split(space(ed-st),' ')) pe AS i,x;
```

Then I use the brickhouse udf `bhouse_intersect_array`

```
select count(1)
from range_array cross join <source_tablename>
where size(bhouse_intersect_array(source_array, range_array)) > 0
```